# Finding two variables from different arrays to get a specific sum in specific complexity

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

I'm a computer science student and it my first year!
So, I see this have to be very easy but some how I just can't catch it in my head.

So - exercise it self:

Def gets two arrays with real numbers (ints) and some  S (int).
Need to find X (some int from array 1) + Y (int from array 2) = S.
BUT - complexity has to be O(n+m) where n & m are lengths of arrays.

```
def finding_sum(arr1, arr2, s):
  for i in arr1:
    if (s-i in arr2):
      return i, s-i
```

I thought about that - but IN module is just like going through the full array and this is O(n*m).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the second list to a set. The conversion is `O(m)`,and set lookup is O(1).

```
def finding_sum(arr1, arr2, s):
    set2 = set(arr2)
    for i in arr1:
        if s-i in set2:
            return i, s-i
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can create an auxiliary data structure:

```
def finding_sum(arr1, arr2, s):
    lookup = {s-n for n in arr1}
    for n in arr2:
        if n in lookup:
            return s-n, n
```

The set `lookup` takes linear time to create and provides a `O(1)` contains check. You can shorten this using `next`:

```
def finding_sum(arr1, arr2, s):
    lookup = {s-n for n in arr1}
    return next((s-n, n) for n in arr2 if n in lookup)
```

You might even use set intersetion to get a one-liner, but give away any short-circuiting:

```
def finding_sum(arr1, arr2, s):
    return next((s-n, n) for n in set(arr2).intersection(map(s.__sub__, arr1)))
```

Comment: Thank you! You're great =3